# Show shipping methods without zip code

Tags: shipping, shipping-address

All my shipping methods have the same price, regardless of the zip code. Is it possible to show the shipping methods without needing to enter a zip code?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify for which countries the zip code is optional. Have a look at **Configuration / General / Countries Options**.

In addition, you will need to remove the client side (*) required note, e.g. using CSS, which frankly is not really nice.